# SQL Server trigger to update Sharepoint List

Tags: sql-server-2005, sharepoint-2007

So, it looks like I'm gonna have to replicate a couple of reference tables from my SS2k5 db on SP2k7 in order to do dropdown boxes on my document library. Small tables, maybe a hundred entries, and not often updated. Ths SP Server is not the SS server.

I know how to build triggers, but how do I reference the SP table to update it from the SS trigger, and what are the authentication issues?

Anybody do this before?

I know there is a thing called Business Catalog Data or something like that, but I don't have full privs on this SP site, so I'm likely not to be able to get to that, and I've never used it before, hence the trigger idea.

Comment: You could create a linked server from the SQL 2005 server to over the SharePoint 2007 database, but if the tables aren't often updated, triggers might be overkill. What about setting up a SQL job that replicates the table over to SP once a morning or something like that? You could still use the linked server for that.

Comment: Well, now there's something I've never done -- create a linked server to SP. What provider?

Comment: SharePoint has an underlying database. Assuming that it's a separate server but that it's still a SQL Server, you should use the SQLNCLIxx provider (SQL Server Native Client version xx). If you name your linked server "SP", for example, you can access its tables using SP.database_name.owner_name.table_name, such as "SP.SharePoint.dbo.Users", or create a SYNONYM for the table on the other server to abstract away the location.

Answer (score 0):

Does it really need to be real time via a trigger? Or can it be delayed and processed via an ETL job? If the latter is acceptable, I recommend taking a look at [Extracting and Loading SharePoint Data in SQL Server Integration Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh368261.aspx). I have used this adapter on past projects to transfer data between SQL Server and SharePoint.

P.S. I would not recommend writing directly to the SharePoint content database. Making changes directly to a content database is not supported and is not considered a best practice.